# Load operations in pig script sequential or parallel?

Tags: apache-pig

I have 2 load statements in a pig script as below:

a=load 'file1.dat' using HCatLoader();

b=load 'file2.dat' using HcatLoader();

After these, I have some transformations on a and b seperately. If we run this pig script in batch mode, does the load and transformations of both files happen sequentially or in parallel? I was thinking that pig optimises this script and runs both the loads in parallel. But not 100% sure. Can anyone comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

Each load command will run in parallel, but the commands in pig script will run serial.

Comment: The statement is not clear. Can you please add more details. If the commands in pig script run serial, how the load command will run in parallel ?