# Pig script: Are the tables read in parallel or in sequence?

Tags: apache-pig

In the following Pig script, are the two tables read one after the other or in parallel?

```
a = LOAD 'sampledb1.tb1' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
a_filter = FILTER a BY cpd_dt == '20150602';

b = LOAD 'sampledb2.tb2' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b_filter = FILTER b BY cpd_dt == '20150602';

/* do some analysis on the data in the above tables*/
```

Answer (score 0):

From the scripts and tables I've created, I've noticed that the tables read one by one.

Comment: This question seems to be asked in another post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052356/load-operations-in-pig-script-sequential-or-parallel

Comment: :Mapreduce plan generated by PIG command EXPLAIN shows that they have been read parallel.So i am confused of what i can infer from the plan and the script.